# How to display tablayout over ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

How to display the Tablayout over my ViewPager. I have tried many things but nothing worked out. Please have a look over the screenshot of how its displaying:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaQVn.png)

Here is my code snippet :

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/main_header"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="220dp"
         android:clipToPadding="false"
         android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">
     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
         android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:gravity="bottom"
         app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
         app:tabGravity="center"
         app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
         app:tabMode="fixed"
         app:tabPaddingBottom="20dp"
         app:tabRippleColor="@color/black" />
   </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestion will be great help!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this layout

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPaddingBottom="20dp"
            app:tabRippleColor="#000000" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp">

   <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/MyStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I have used that but I think my tab layout is going backside of ViewPager. and because of that tablayout is not working

Comment: try to put TabLayout above viewpager i think it will solve your problem.

Comment: sorry bro u need same as Screenshot?

Comment: no exactly opposite, In the screenshot i have already acheived that. I want to bring my three dots down

Comment: here one,two three you can put dots,   sorry for too big ss :)

Comment: got your solution or not

Answer (score 0):

**try this xml** and check your xml you have inserted tablayout inside viewpager

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="#DACFCF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="20dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="#000" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using ContraintLayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="20dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@color/black" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Piyush Is it still the same effect or something different? Also is this your full layout or are you nesting it inside something else?

Comment: @Piyush also, ideally, where do you want the tabs, at the top of the screen or bottom? I've changed my layout as I noticed the attributes you were using originally contradicted mine.

Comment: Its the same effect. And I want my tablayout over the viewpager and bottom of the viewpager. Please check screenshot

Comment: @Piyush I'm more confused now. I thought the image shows what you have but not what you need. also from the screenshot, it's not exactly clear what belongs to your tablayout and what to your viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place one view over another you can use [constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to achieve this really fast.

**Here is an example:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="I am view B"
    android:background="#1D1DD5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View B"
    android:background="#ff2222"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Your layout will look like this**

[image]

You can change how your layout will look, this is just an example to expose you to `ConstraintLayout` - feel free to change my example according to your needs.